# Congrats to those who completed the January 2016 Challenge!

Tags: discussion, congratulations, challenges

I wanted to post this up to congratulate those who have achieved the Electorate badge in January 2016! Here are those who have completed the job:

## Max Goodridge

## Jonathan Musso

## Rory Alsup

And because they were such good sports about it, I'm including these two who completed the challenge a little early:

## DucatiKiller

## Zaid

Congratulations to all!

**NOTE:** The system will only allow me to have three outstanding bounties at a time. The three which are outstanding at the posting of this will not allow me to *award* the bounties for 24 hours. Please be expecting your points then!

Comment: It was an excellent idea, and appears to have had a positive effect overall. Many thanks!

Comment: @MaxGoodridge - Thanks for cleaning up my spelling mistake! :D

Comment: @Paulster2 No worries! Easily done.

Comment: Paulster2, 'Rory Alsup'... srry but I can't suggest an edit ha